# plus width of div in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, properties

i have sample div (width: 10%) and a sample button, i want when click on the button, div's width plus with 10.

first click >> width = 20%

second click >> width = 30%
.
.
.

can do this with DOM?

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Progresse Bar +10%">
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
width: 10%;
height: 200px;
background-color: rgb(173, 230, 18);
}
```

**js**

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", func);
function func() {
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.width+=10;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve the behaviour you describe as follows:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", incrementWidth);

// Initialize the width
let width = 10;
setWidthOnElement(width);

function incrementWidth() {
  width += 10;
  setWidthOnElement(width);
}

function setWidthOnElement(width) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.width = `${width}%`;
}
```

```css
.progress-bar {
   height: 200px;
   background-color: rgb(173, 230, 18);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Progresse Bar +10%">
```